# IMPORTXML error - empty table

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importxml

I am trying to import a table from the lower part of the following website to Google Sheets: 
https://vistacapital.com.br/

I used the formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://vistacapital.com.br";"//*[@id='sos-vmf']/td[2]/text()")
```

but the output is empty.

I need the value underneath the word "cota", to the right of the word "Vista Multiestrategia FIM"

or import the entire table, with the bottom formula, but it no longer works:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://vistacapital.com.br";"table";1)
```

Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't have those data, because they are injected into the table by JS. That's why when you use this formula, the table is empty:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://vistacapital.com.br"; "TABLE"; 1)
```

All you can get is this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://vistacapital.com.br"; "//*")
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the field I need ("cota" value)

Comment: @Junior "Unfortunately, you can't have those data..."